# Security concerns and architecture in PHP

Tags: php, security

My little program, based on PHP, MySql, Jquery and Ajax, provides login and show data from  database. Login.html –> check-login.php –> success-login.php <-> show-data.php

My questions:

1. any security concers I should worry about or improve in general.
2. regarding to `$_SESSION`, is it possible that someone adds `$_SESSION['mytime']` in a php file on a remote computer, and pretends to be a authorized user?
3. I saw a video on Youtube claiming 80% logins can be broken (by proxy and password dictionary), shall I set the maximum time a user can login to prevent it or other suggestions?
4. I can format data on either MySQL and php (server side) or javascript (client side), shall I always do it in client side, or for example, if having 10 functions, 8 in client side and 2 in server side and so on.

My codes are listed as below:

login.html (call check-login.php)

check-login.php

```
// connect database by PDO
// if username and password (in md5) are matched
session_start();
$_SESSION['mytime'] = time();
header('location:success-login.php');
```

success-login.php

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['mytime'])) {
  header('location:login.html');
   exit;
}
//use Jquery and Ajax to fetch data from database in show-data.php
```

show-data.php

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['mytime'])) {
  header('location:login.html');
   exit;
}
//PDO database operation and return data in JSON
```

Comment: You're totally not understanding how php sessions and php code works. there is NOTHING a remote user can do to affect $_SESSION except via your code. Putting a max login time is pointless - brute force attacks occur to GAIN a login. you need to restrict login ATTEMPTS.

Comment: @MarcB - Perhaps better to let them have (say) three attempts. If unsuccessful they have to wait for a hour before trying again. Depends on the application

Comment: don't use md5, use something like bcrypt

Comment: You mention md5 in the comments. Please note that the MD5 hashing algorithm is **not** secure, and can be hacked very easily. For password management, I recommend using a library such as [this one](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat), which is written by one of the developers on the PHP team with responsibility for security -- it's probably the best solution out there.

Comment: @Stefan why not use md5? MD5 is fast and combined with a 'private' seed will do the trick for reverse lookups if that is your concern.

Comment: @JimmyKane Why not? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security

Comment: Have a look at SDCs comment. Even with a private seed md5 is just too "efficient" and allows easy brute forcing. Having a fixed salt will also allow the generation of rainbow tables

Comment: I can only recommend php-login.net once again. Uses SHA256 and salt, which is much much much much much better than md5.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: @JimmyKane "MD5 is fast". Exactly. That's the problem. Being fast makes brute-forcing a hash fast. And MD5 is very fast, fast enough that brute forcing a *completely random* 8-character alphanumeric password takes *less than an hour* on average, with <$1k in hardware. Or rent similarly fast machines for $2.10/hr from Amazon. And, let me stress, your users' passwords are nowhere near that good.

Comment: @Alasjo you mean about collisions, probalby...

Comment: @derobert Buteforcing a hash after you got it. if you don't have it how are you going to to bruteforce it. And getting it doesn't imply that you are already reading via db? BTW with modern hardware and as you mentioned with amazon services even sha becomes fast to bruteforce.

Comment: @JimmyKane If you assume the database will never leak, then you might as well store them in plain text. But you're not, because you know that database compromises happen. And you're right, neither SHA-1 nor SHA-2 should be used for storing passwords either; instead, use bcrypt, scrypt, or PBKDF-2. Those are *designed* to be used for storing passwords, so they *are* slow.

Comment: (Also, of course, connecting to the DB directly is not the only way hashes leak. SQL injection is another big one)

Comment: @derobert +1 for sql injection, but if you have a database leak, I mean man no md5 will save you or sha1. So step 1 is to make your app safe as the user asks and then care about how much encrypted your passes are.

Comment: @JimmyKane If you have a database leak, a proper password hash will make an attack against the hash *very* slow. Easily 100ms per attempt (or more, if you can spare the CPU time and get the user to wait—its configurable). This makes a non-targeted offline attack infeasible, even on pretty bad passwords. And remember that actual users re-use passwords, so by doing this, you're protecting their other accounts. Some of which may be much more important than your site (e.g., banking, email).

Comment: @derobert ok agree with that.

Comment: I use MD5 it is because wordpress is using it. I understand php.net recommends crypt.

Comment: using per-user, random, large salts is at least as important as the hashing algorithm itself. Don't forget your salt! No salt = asking for collisions (as in two users using the same password) and rainbow-tables.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are many security concerns like: [Five common Web application vulnerabilities](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/five-common-web-application-vulnerabilities)
2. No it's not possible that the user set/change your `$_SESSION` variable by his self.
3. You can prevent user to chose a simple password or you can put a [captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA), after for example five time wrong password entrance. (Yahoo! does it) and so on ...
4. I didn't get what you are exactly looking for.

Comment: Regarding to Point 4: format data I mean data functions such as data validation and sanitization and so on. For example, the time is in the format of '17:30:00' on database, I need '17:30'. So I can 1. format it in server side SQL or in PHP or client side in javascript. I used TIME_FORMAT in SQL in my case because it was supported in MySQL and reduce data to pass to the client side. <b>Is it a good practice?</b>

Comment: Furthermore, in principle, sever side should be for data process (fetch, save data and so on), client side is for css, javascript kind of job, saying if there are 10 functions for data process (should be on client side), in practice, will it be better to put some on client side and some on server side?

Comment: @NZhang First i think it's better to store time as linux timestamp in mysql because it's 10 chars and it's easy in calculation/convertion. Second i think you should do important functions at the back end (server side) cause of security reasons.

Comment: 1. I set data type in date and time in MySql,

Comment: for 4. I would say one easy thing, never trust what a client sends you... I would do everything server side and just feed the client with what has to be displayed...

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things you should have in mind when you're developing such an application. Depending on the sensitivity of the data you're displaying from the database, you may want to start using HTTPS connections instead of plain HTTP. This is what I would usually do to boost the security:

- Create encrypted sessions - use mcrypt and store the key needed to decrypt the session on the client's side via a cookie. This way, even if somebody eventually has some access to the path where the sessions are stored on the server, he won't be able to decode the sessions because the keys are stored on the client's side.
- Do not use any SQL in the URLs and **ALWAYS** check if the submitted data is valid - i.e. if the record id exists, is the entered data valid and so on.
- Watch out for cross site scripting
- **ALWAYS** use password encryption and if you have sensitive data - try encrypting that as well.

Regarding your other questions:

1. I am not sure what your question is. `$_SESSION` is stored on the server side. It can be changed only by the scripts which run on that server or manually (if you edit the `$_SESSION` file by hand)
2. Use a captcha (reCaptcha) when user fails to login X times. If you'd like you can add a lock - if the user fails to login 5 times the user will be locked and an email with unlock instructions will be sent to the user's email address.
3. I don't know what exactly you mean by `format` (is it parsing, or styling). If I was responding to AJAX requests, I would format the data and output **only** the data that needs to be displayed. For example, if I'm showing information about a user, I would output his `username`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`email` but not his `password`, `password_salt`,`bank_account` and any other sensitive data.
4. As a followup to point 3 - when you format the data from the server side, it's up to you how to display it. You may do that via JavaScript or you can directly output it as a response to the AJAX request. It's up to you.

The code you've provided us is something I wouldn't use because it doesn't check against a valid user. If the user has a session with `mytime` variable it assumes the user has is valid. I would store `user_id` and `password`(encrypted) in the session and then check if those values match in a database. This way, in case the user gets deleted or changes his password, all of his other sessions will become invalid.